# Development of an accurate multiple person counting solution using OpenCV and C++

Tags: c++, opencv, detection, counting

The program can currently count single people quite accurately.

I use a frame difference approach.
The problem is, often when two people walk under the camera at the same time, the program thinks of them as one 'blob'. And so that is where the innacuracy creeps in.

The code below is the two most important functions with regards to this question.

```
   //--------------------------Draw object location--------------------------------
    void drawObject(vector<MultiplePeople> themultiPeople,Mat &frame)**{
    //recieves the location of all the objects on the screen
    //For loop : draws a circle, cross and the location of each object
    for(int i =0; i<themultiPeople.size(); i++)
    {
    //Draws circle
    cv::circle(frame,cv::Point(themultiPeople.at(i).getXpos(),themultiPeople.at(i).getYpos()),15,cv::Scalar(0,0,255));
    //Draws Line
    cv::line(frame,cv::Point(themultiPeople.at(i).getXpos(),themultiPeople.at(i).getYpos()+15),
    cv::Point(themultiPeople.at(i).getXpos(),themultiPeople.at(i).getYpos()-15),Scalar(0,255,0),1);
    //Draws Line
    cv::line(frame,cv::Point(themultiPeople.at(i).getXpos()+15,themultiPeople.at(i).getYpos()),
    cv::Point(themultiPeople.at(i).getXpos()-15,themultiPeople.at(i).getYpos()),Scalar(0,255,0),1);
    //Insert persons location
    cv::putText(frame,intToString(themultiPeople.at(i).getXpos())+ " , " + intToString(themultiPeople.at(i).getYpos()),
    cv::Point(themultiPeople.at(i).getXpos(),themultiPeople.at(i).getYpos()+20),1,1,Scalar(0,255,0));
    }
    }
    //----------Stores location of persons in a array and counts---------------------
    void storematrix(int numberpeople[max_people][2])
    {
    //--------Declare variables-------
    int pos;
    double dist, xdistance, ydistance, smallest, person_onscreen, temp;
    //Create a array of all the distances
    double distance[max_people];
    //make the array full of zeros
    memset(distance, 0 , sizeof(distance));
    person_onscreen = 0;
    pos = 0;
    //------Stores the person in a array-------------
    //if it is the first frame and there is only one person
if (frames == 0 && peoplecount[frames] == 1)
{
location[0][0][0] = numberpeople[0][0];
location[0][0][1] = numberpeople[0][1];
position_location[0] = 0;
frames = frames + 1;
}
else
{
//if it is not the first frame
if (frames > 0)
{
//if there is only one person
if (peoplecount[frames] == 1)
{
location[position_location[0]+1][0][0] = numberpeople[0][0];
location[position_location[0]+1][0][1] = numberpeople[0][1];
}
//there is more then one and the closest location should be stored
else
{
for (int x = 0; x < peoplecount[frames] ; x++)
{
//determine the distances from each object to the previous object
xdistance = abs(numberpeople[x][0] - location[position_location[0]][0][0]);
ydistance = abs(numberpeople[x][1] - location[position_location[0]][0][1]);
dist = pow(xdistance,2) + pow(ydistance,2);
distance[x] = sqrt(dist);
}
smallest = 1000;
//determines the smallest distance
for ( int y = 0; y < (peoplecount[frames]); y++)
{
if (distance[y] < smallest)
{
smallest = distance[y];
pos = y;
}
}
location[position_location[0]+1][0][0] = numberpeople[pos][0];
location[position_location[0]+1][0][1] = numberpeople[pos][1];
}
//------Count the amount of people in and out-------------
if (location[position_location[0]+1][0][1] < dHeight/2 && location[position_location[0]][0][1] > dHeight/2)
{
PeopleIn = PeopleIn + 1;
}
if (location[position_location[0]+1][0][1] > dHeight/2 && location[position_location[0]][0][1] < dHeight/2)
{
PeopleOut = PeopleOut + 1;
}
position_location[0] = position_location[0] + 1;
frames = frames + 1;
}
}
}
```

If anyone can help I would really appreciate it.

I have thought of using a different approach, using LibPaBOD to recognize people's heads from above and count those rather? Would that work? Any tips?

Comment: you could try HoG pedestrian detector. Face/head detection might work too, but typically pedestrian-counting applications use different image resolutions (pixel per face) than face detection algorithms. BUT I would give it a try!

Comment: With these questions, it helps if you could link to am image showing the problem.

Comment: Your code would also be more readabel if you'd write `for (auto& person : themultiPeople)` and add a `cvPoint MultiplePeople::getPos()`.